# Python 3 join data from large files that are sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple large files (> 5M rows of data) that are sorted on a unique timestamp. All the files contain virtually all the same timestamps except for a handful of randomly missing rows (< 1000). I'd like to efficiently join the data from all the files into a single dataset with one row per timestamp, preferably using a generator.

Except for the missing rows, I could just use zip:

```
def get_data(list_of_iterables):
    for data in zip(*list_of_iterables):
        yield data
```

However, since there are some missing rows, I need to join the data on timestamp instead of simply zipping. I can simply ignore any rows that don't have matching timestamps in every file.

Is there a pythonic way to implement this functionality in a few lines?

My approach would be to advance each iterable in turn until it's timestamp is no longer less than the maximum timestamp for the group of iterables. Whenever all the timestamps match, yield a row and advance all the iterables. But, the logic seems messy when I try to implement this approach.

Edit: Performance.

The implementation needs to start returning rows without reading all the data into memory first. It takes a while to read all the data and many times only the first handful of rows needs to be examined.

Comment: please add some example data

Comment: I would suggest for you to take a look at pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/). It has tools to do this exact type of merging that you´re mentioning.

Comment: @Ivan I noticed the Pandas library when I was Googling this issue. The library looks very useful for many of the operations that I am doing. I currently rely heavily on Numpy, but I am going to investigate Pandas when I get some time.

Comment: @RandomBits: pandas is built on top of `numpy` arrays. It is built to make it easier the operations you describe in particular [to merge, join data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing the following code to solve my problem, which turned out to be lighter than I expected:

```
def advance_values(iters):
    for it in iters:
        yield next(it)

def align_values(iters, values, key):
    for it, value in zip(iters, values):
        while (value[0],value[1]) < key:
            value = next(it)
        yield value

def merge_join(*iters):
    values = list(advance_values(iters))
    while True:
        if len(values) != len(iters):
            return
        tms = [(v[0],v[1]) for v in values]
        max_tm = max(tms)
        if all((v[0],v[1]) == max_tm for v in values):
            yield values
            values = list(advance_values(iters))
        else:
            values = list(align_values(iters, values, max_tm))
```

Comment: sorry. updated my answer and saw now only that you posted a solution  yourself...

Answer (score 1):

If each iterable in `list_of_iterables` is sorted by `timestamp` then you could use [`heapq.merge()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) to merge them taking into account possible gaps in the data and [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group records with the same timestamp:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

for timestamp, group in groupby(merge(*list_of_iterables), 
                                key=attrgetter('timestamp')):
    print(timestamp, list(group)) # same timestamp
```

The implementation yields groups without reading all the data into memory first.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be to use a dictionary with timestamps as keys and the rest of the data in the rows as values, then for each row in each file, add it to the dictionary only if an item with the same timestamp (key) isn't already present.

However, if you truly are dealing with giant data sets (which it seems like you are in this case), then the approach you mention in your original question would be your best option.

Comment: I can see how that would work, but seem my comment on performance as this method seems like it needs to read all the data into memory first.

Comment: @RandomBits OK, thanks for the extra information. I can't think of a better way to solve the problem than the one you gave in your original question, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i got interested in the problem (had a similar problem recently) and worked a bit on it. you could try something like this:

```
import io
import datetime
from csv import DictReader

file0 = io.StringIO('''timestamp,data
2015-06-01 10:00, data00
2015-06-01 11:00, data01
2015-06-01 12:00, data02
2015-06-01 12:30, data03
2015-06-01 13:00, data04
''')

file1 = io.StringIO('''timestamp,data
2015-06-01 09:00, data10
2015-06-01 10:30, data11
2015-06-01 11:00, data12
2015-06-01 12:30, data13
''')

class Data(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.timestamp = None
        self.data = None

    @staticmethod
    def new_from_dict(dct=None):
        if dct is None:
            return None
        ret = Data()
        ret.data = dct['data'].strip()
        ret.timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(dct['timestamp'],
                                                   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        return ret

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        return self.timestamp < other.timestamp

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        return self.timestamp > other.timestamp

    def __str__(self):
        ret = '{0.__class__.__name__}'.format(self) +\
              '(timestamp={0.timestamp}, data={0.data})'.format(self)
        return ret


def next_or_none(reader):
    try:
        return Data.new_from_dict(next(reader))
    except StopIteration:
        return None


def yield_in_order(reader0, reader1):

    data0 = next_or_none(reader0)
    data1 = next_or_none(reader1)

    while not data0 == data1 == None:

        if data0 is None:
            yield None, data1
            data1 = next_or_none(reader1)
            continue
        if data1 is None:
            yield data0, None
            data0 = next_or_none(reader0)
            continue

        while data0 < data1:
            yield data0, None
            data0 = next_or_none(reader0)

        while data0 > data1:
            yield None, data1
            data1 = next_or_none(reader1)

        if data0 is not None and data1 is not None:
            if data0.timestamp == data1.timestamp:
                yield data0, data1
                data0 = next_or_none(reader0)
                data1 = next_or_none(reader1)

csv0 = DictReader(file0)
csv1 = DictReader(file1)

FMT = '{!s:50s} | {!s:50s}'
print(FMT.format('file0', 'file1'))
print(101*'-')
for dta0, dta1 in yield_in_order(csv0, csv1):
    print(FMT.format(dta0, dta1))
```

this is for 2 files only.